# Junction object scenario

Tags: junction-object

I have created a junction object with name JO and have 2 other objects candidate and position, have master detail relation ship form both object to junction object. My scenario is that 1 candidate related to many position and 1 position related to many candidate. That's is why I created the junction object. I have created a record in junction object and created 3 records in candidate with junction object record same as in position I created 3 records with junction object record. Now when I go to the junction object I can see all the position and candidate records related to the junction object records, that is 3 position records and 3 candidate records. But still not able to understand how 1 candidate related to many positions and 1 position related to many candidates. Can any one here guide me what I am doing wrong or any thing else I need to do over this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the following image I found on search engine:
[image]

Here a team member is related to project. So there can be two scenarios:

1. A **team member** can be related to multiple project
2. A **project** can have multiple **team members**

To achieve this we create a object which will have reference to **team member** and **project** to establish relationship. Let's say the object name is: **Project Team Member**

So, for the scenario 1 you can create multiple "**Project Team member**" records which will have different **team member** in each record but same **project** reference. This way a **team member** can be related to multiple **projects**

For scenario 2, you can create "**Project Team member**" record which will have different Project reference but same **team member** reference.

This way multiple team members can be related to single project as well as with multiple projects and vice-versa. The best way to understand is do it practically you will understand how it is many-to-many relationship.