# How to set uniqueness on child for delete,How to relate parent to child while insert?

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image: I think now you can able to understand]I am creating a page that i have to insert multiple parent and multiple child in single insert call in single page .
Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="ManageListController" showHeader="false">
 <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock title="Bulk Quotelineitem Create" id="wtable">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!colist}" var="a" >
      <apex:column >
          <apex:commandlink Value="Add child" action="{!addchild}" rerender="wtable">
         <apex:param assignTo="{!parentname}" value="{!a.name}" Name="parentname777"/>
         </apex:commandlink>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Parent">
            <apex:inputField value="{!a.Phone}"/>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Name">
            <apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column >
         <apex:commandButton value="Delete Account" action="{!deleteaccount}" rerender="wtable">
         <apex:param assignTo="{!parentname}" value="{!a.name}" Name="parentname777"/>
         </apex:commandButton>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="1">
         <apex:pageblockTable value="{!colist[a]}" var="c" >
         <apex:column headerValue="Contact Name">
           <apex:inputField value="{!c.name}"/>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column headerValue="Account id">
          <apex:inputField value="{!c.Accountid}"/>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column >
          <apex:commandlink Value="Add contact" action="{!addcontact}" rerender="wtable">
         <apex:param assignTo="{!parentname}" value="{!a.name}" Name="parentname777"/>
         </apex:commandlink>
         </apex:column>
         <apex:column >
         <apex:commandButton Value="Delete contact" action="{!deletecontact}" >

         </apex:commandbutton>
         </apex:column>
         </apex:pageblockTable>
         </apex:column>

      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageblock>
   <apex:commandButton Value="Add Account"   action="{!addaccount}" rerender="wtable"/>
 </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class ManageListController{
       Public set<account> acclist{get ; set;}
       Public string parentname{get ; set;}
       Public string childname{get ; set;}
     Public Map<Account,list<contact>> colist{ get; set;}
     public list<contact> ctlist{get; set;}
     integer count;

          public ManageListController(){
         count=1;   
         acclist=new set<account>();      
         colist=new Map<Account,list<contact>>();
         Account acc= new account(name='acc'+count);
         ctlist=new list<contact>();
         contact ct=new contact(Lastname='Karthika');

         ctlist.add(ct);
         colist.put(acc,ctlist); 
         acclist.add(acc);
         }

       Public void addaccount(){
         count = count+1;
         Account acc= new account(Name='acc'+count);
         ctlist=new list<contact>();
         contact ct=new contact(Lastname='Karthika');
         ctlist.add(ct);
         colist.put(acc,ctlist);
         acclist.add(acc);
       }
       Public Void addcontact(){
       Account acc= new account(name=parentname);
       list<contact> ctlist=colist.get(acc);
       contact ct=new contact(Lastname='Karthika');
       ctlist.add(ct);
       colist.put(acc,ctlist);
       } 
       Public void deletecontact(){

      }
      Public Void deleteaccount(){
      Account acc= new account(name=parentname);
      colist.remove(acc);
     }
     Public pagereference save(){
     id acid;
     Map<account,id> Mapaccountid= new Map<account,id>();
     set<account> accl=colist.keyset();
     list<account> acli=new list<account>();
     for(account a:accl){
     acli.add(a);
     Mapaccountid.put(a,a.id);
     }
     insert acli;

     list<contact> colis=new list<contact>();

     For(Account acc:accl){
      For(contact col:ctlist){
      acid=Mapaccountid.get(acc);
      contact co=new contact();
      co.lastname='france';
      co.accountid=acid;
     colis.add(co);
     }}
     insert colis;
     return null;
      }
}
```

I Cant able to put uniqueness for deleting a child record .I dont know how i cant relate parent to child while inserting .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you are not clear about your datamodel. Reading your code I was not able to figure exactly how the ERD looks like an what you want to achieve. So it's unclear what you are asking exactly.

But conceptually this basics might help you:

- draw your ERD (entity relationship diagram)
- mind that there are only 1:n relationships natively
- an m:n relationship needs a junction object
- Lookup- and MasterDetail relationships work always from child to parent (=master)

Based on this you might rethink your model and maybe rephrase your question.

What I noticed in your code that can't work:

- I can't see a query to populate your pageblocktable
- your action functions have no DML to store anything
- your list consists of contacts, addparent and addchild deal with accounts and the pageblocktitle says 'Bulk Quotelineitem Create' - how that can fit together?

To learn more about m:n relationships and junctions object I would recommend that you search for it. You need at least 3 objects: the two you wand to relate and the third to glue them together (this is the junction object). At the junction object you need a relation to both other objects to make it work. It's like Mathew Lamb said [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gxgNAAQ):

> A many-to-many relationship consists of three objects: Object A and
>   Object B are the two primary objects, and Object J is the junction
>   that enables the many to many.
>
> Object A  <--M/D--  Object J  --M/D--> Object B
>
> So on Object J you need to create two Master-Detail relationships, one
>   that points to Object A and one that points to Object B.

There are also a couple of other useful links:

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junction-object
- [Junction object scenario](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/junction-object-scenario)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jy5JZ42XN6Q
- https://www.google.de/search?q=salesfore+howto+junction+object

In general I would also reconsider your UI. It doesn't look very usable to me. But first get clear on your model. I could suggest you something but therefore you need to tell a bit more what you are going to achieve. The exact requirement. Verbosely.

Comment: now you understood what i am trying to do

Comment: I have a problem with delete child button and in regarding button i cant able to relate account and contact .it is saving as two different records

Comment: to be honest: no, I still don't figure it without very long thinking. Take a few words and tell us your story in plain english, please. The screenshot looks not like anything I have seen before. Nothing familiar, Nothing standard, very exotic and unconventional, at least for me...

Comment: K just my logic is to insert multiple parent and its related multiple child in vf page

Comment: to relate account and contact there is only ONE standard field called Contact.AccountId - now do you want to use that? If so you have to set it. But there is only ONE Account per contact. If you need more, you NEED a junction object. It's all about the model first. Are you aware of that? No direct m:n.

Comment: And please add to "parent" and "child" their object names. Are the parents "Accounts" and the children "Contacts"? This we must understand first.